# rhel routing without NAT using iptables

Tags: iptables, ip, redhat, routing

I need to set up routing, preferably with iptables, that does no NAT.  Basically I will have a number of clients on subnet 192.168.1.0/24 and they need their traffic to go through a gateway, say 192.168.1.1 and that gateway then passes on the request, without translating the original address, to another gateway, say 192.168.0.100. What I really want to do is use iptables so I can configure a fine grain firewall to do the routing but all I can find info on is how to do this with NAT.  Which I have done before.  Any insight on how to do the routing without NAT?

Comment: "assigning us a Class C subnet" -- I'll bet they aren't.

Comment: Our institution owns a Class B block of public addresses.  They are assigning us a Class C block.  Why do you say they are not?

Comment: If your institution "owns" a class B subnet, they cannot, by the very *definition* of a classful addressing, assign you a class C subnet out of that block.  Cannot be done.  That's before we start into the issue of classful addressing being declared obsolete over 20 years ago...

Comment: Fair enough, call it what you like, but they are "allocating" us a class C subnet of addresses and I am stumped on how to do the routing with iptables.  I will edit my original question to generalize it.

Comment: They're not allocating you a class C subnet either.  Classful addressing is *dead*.

Comment: [Start here.](http://lartc.org/howto/)

Comment: your institution owns a /16 and they are assigning you a /24 - as someone else pointed out, classful addressing is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Routing without NAT is just like routing with NAT... only without the NAT.  You add routing table entries to indicate next-hop destinations.

Firewalling without NAT is just like firewalling with NAT... only without the NAT.  You add firewall rules to permit traffic with certain attributes (source/dest addresses and ports, protocols, state parameters, etc) in like with organisational policy.

Answer (score 1):

No need nat here, add your deny/accept rules to `FORWARD` chain of `filter` table,

also don't forget to enable forwading on both devices:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
```

or setup it via sysctl (`net.ipv4.conf.all.forwading=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`)